# Is there an analog of the Sleep function in c++, but which could continue working until the time expires?

Tags: c++, multithreading, timer, sleep

Is there a function that could suspend the stream for a certain time, and if some event occurred (for example: the user pressed a button), then the function would resume the stream before the time expires? If not, what can you advise?

As an example, I wrote a function that takes 2 parameters:
the delay time in milliseconds;
bool-a variable that, if changed to true, will terminate the loop ahead of time.

```
#include <iostream>
float Timer(clock_t milliseconds, bool& stop) {
    clock_t start = clock(), now;

    while ((now = clock() - start) <= milliseconds) {
        if (stop) {
            return now / 1000.f;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip: You need an event loop.

Comment: ...event loop that calls a function that either will sleep for the specified amount of time, or will return early if any of a given set of file descriptors has data that can be read. (e.g., https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html, or https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html, or https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/epoll.7.html)